# How to convert HTML structure into HTML5

Tags: html

I wonder how to reorganize the following html structure into HTML5 structure Semantically ? I'm thinking to place in section, figure and dl but no idea how to organize it correctly. Hope someone experience with HTML 5 semantic structure can show me the correct way. Thanks.

```
<div class="product-list">
  <h1>Product Category A</h1>
  <div class="item odd">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"><a href="image.jpg"><img src="img/product.jpg"></a></div>
      <div class="title">Product 1
        <span>Sub title 1</span>                
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <div class="col-left">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="col-right">Price: 50</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item even">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"><a href="image.jpg"><img src="img/product.jpg"></a></div>
      <div class="title">Product 2
        <span>Sub title 2</span>                
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <div class="col-left">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="col-right">Price: 70</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item even">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"><a href="image.jpg"><img src="img/product.jpg"></a></div>
      <div class="title">Product 3
        <span>Sub title 3</span>                
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <div class="col-left">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="col-right">Price: 20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no official way I believe... mostly good ideas to clean up the divitis and be semantic about it.  Like... if it's a list, make it `<ul>` and the list items `<li>`.

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could replace `<div class="product-list">` with a `<section>` and wrap your `h1` into a `header`.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 is simply a specification. It introduces a [new set of elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp). So, in advising you in "converting an HTML structure" into HTML5, I'd suggest you take a look at the new tags and use them.

I see a lot of `div` tags in your current markup. An HTML5 compliant site wouldn't look like this. [Check out this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/04/designing-a-html-5-layout-from-scratch/).

To give you a starting point, this sample uses many of the new tags and would be considered HTML5 compliant:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <section></section>
        <article></article>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that <main> (still) isn't supported in any version of IE though, would need to make adjustments in the CSS to get it functioning as expected

Comment: That's a good point. Some "cutting edge" specifications suffer compatibility problems. Do your research before deploying any production code.